# Request in 10 tables. Tables have different structures

Tags: php, mysql, database

Please suggest me how to implement such a thing? I have 10 tables - 10 dictionaries in different categories. All tables have different structures.
User types a word, then need to display the results from all the tables, and you need to specify what is the result of what the table.
Sorry for machine translation...

```
$tables = array("test_prefixvoc", 
                "test_prefixvoc_br",
                "test_prefixVoc_fraze",
                "test_prefixVoc_Gloss2",
                "test_prefixvoc_Lingvo",
                "test_prefixvoc_orfo",
                "test_prefixvoc_rb",
                "test_prefixvoc_sinonim",
                "test_prefixVoc_sinonim2",
                "test_prefixvoc_tolk");

$names = array('name', 'NAME', 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name1', 
'name', 'name', 'Name1', 'Name1', 'NAME');

include 'DB.php';
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$word =  $_GET["word"];

$array = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($tables); $i++) {
    $dbs = mysql_select_db($tables[$i], $con);
    mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tables[$i] WHERE    $names[$i]='$word'");          //query
    $array[$i] = mysql_fetch_row($result);  

    mysql_close();  
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: At the moment i'm writing 10 queries, try to understand 2d arrays. I'll save there results.

Comment: Let's see the code you have so far, and tell us what issues you're seeing.  We can help more once we see some code.

Comment: That code looks pretty reasonable.  If you want to keep track of which table the record came from, you might do `$array[$tables[i]] = mysql_fetch_row($result)`.  What isn't working?

Comment: $array[$tables[i]] = mysql_fetch_row($result)   Thanks, it looks like very usefull. But at the moment i don't know how to handle array in JS code...

Comment: You should ask another question or edit this one to make it clear that the issue you're having is handling your results in JavaScript.  You'll want to make it clear if you're using AJAX, jQuery, or just doing things manually.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a specific query for each table, process all of the results, and display the processed message to the user.

Such is the cost of not having a normalized database structure.